# Javascript function argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I am using a javascript function and I am trying to pass a string of characters that come from form fields. I am trying to achieve this:

```
function_name(55,document,form.field1.value,form.field2.value)
```

but I am trying to pass the above as one argument, for example `'44,55,66'`

I tried the following without success:

```
'this.value+','.charAt(0)+document.class.Q_11_2c.value+','.charAt(0)+document.class.Q_12_3c.value'
```

Comment: The function sample should be: 
function_name(55,document.form.field1.value, document.form.field2.value)

Comment: Voting to close ... not a real question and just gibberish unless revised.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your function to accept a single argument, rewrite its definition accordingly and remove any charAt() from its argument in call.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. But may I ask how can I pass as an argument a comma (,)?

Comment: @Evan "Serialize" to a string (Array.join) and "de-serialize" (String.split) later. However, this is a *broken design* -- it's hard to get correct (what if a comma comes in the data?) and just useless at this level. Perhaps update the post to include the *end result* for suggestions on how to correctly write the code.

Answer (score 0):

your function:

```
function_name(dataString) {
//parse the param string to get values you need 
//dataString.split("unique-delimiter")
}
```

now call it as:

```
//make values a single string and pass it to the function
//mydataString = dataArr.join("unique-delimiter") ; 
function_name(mydataString);
```

Comment: just noticed @pst's answer, yes in the calling part you can use Array.join and in the function you can use String.split.